# How save changes to a database after IBindingSource.AddNew() method is used

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, entity-framework-6, bindingsource

I have a form that I use for both editing and inserting new users into a database. I use Entity Framework 6. All my controls (textboxes and one combobox) are bound to specific binding sources  so when I update an entity with:

```
context.user.add(user); 
context.Save();
```

my UI changes. And vice-versa. Now, updating works fine, but I have some problems with inserting of new users. Currently a data grid view has it datasource set, and I have disabled adding rows by clicking on a grid view directly (because I want that part to go through the form):

[image: tasks window]

Okay, so far so good. Now when I want to add a new user, I do this:

```
myDataSource = context.user.Local.ToBindingList();
 myDataSource.AllowNew = true;
```

and later on:

```
myDataSource.AddNew();
```

After calling `AddNew()` the blank row is added to a grid view, and when I insert values in my form, everything shows up automatically in the grid view.

The thing is, I can't really persist this data into a database. If I do:

```
context.Save();
```

nothing happens. I guess because the newly created entity by the AddNew() method is not attached to the current context. But I don't have a reference to it to attach it.

I guess that `AddNew()` creates a new entity, right? And adding it to the datasource. Correct me if I am wrong.

So how to save changes in this case?

Comment: I see you use _context but you call save on context (without the _)

Comment: @SkylerLauren No it is just an example. I use `context` everywhere. But I'll fix that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with getting an added record persisted to the database.  I had same basic setup,  using .Load, and setting the binding source data source = .Local.ToBindingList()
And found an odd fix to the issue.  So under my binding navigator save event, this is the only way I could get newly added records to make it to the database. The last ResetBindings call is just so that the Identity Id shows it's actual DB value instead of zero.

```
    private void mapBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mapBindingSource.EndEdit();  
        mapBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        mapBindingSource.EndEdit();
        _db.SaveChanges();
        mapBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
    }
```